# Eclipse Debugger toString() calls

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging a Java code database (not mine) and in one class the `toString()` method is overriden, and it has the side effect of generating a RuntimeException. I can see the stack trace in the Eclispe debug view when I have the object selected in the Expressions view.

Is there anyway to debug calls from the Eclipse debugger to the `toString()`? I tried setting breakpoints inside the `toString()` method and I put a global break point on all caught and uncaught RuntimeExceptions. But all breakpoints inside the `toString()` method is ignored and Eclipse never breaks on the line that generates the RuntimeException inside `toString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i found the answer in an old Bug-thread for Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12592

Breakpoints are disabled when `toString()` is called in the detail pane, in the debug view, by the debugger.

Answer (score -1):

I can not see how it is not possible for eclipse to debug inside overridden toString method, perhaps the exception was never thrown from toString,

I predict maybe you are trying to access toString from an un-instantiated variable.

Can you be please more specific or elaborate? you can post your code though .. :)

UPDATE:
i assume breakpoint was not invoked by eclipse because error was throws even before the breakpoints was hit. so you might need to change you starting breakpoint and breakdown you code to lines and see where it is thrown.

Comment: The message inside the RuntimeExcption i.e.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is in the runtime, and you might have logical errors causing these vars not instantiated. :)

Comment: why is this downvoted? the question is not even compliant but i was trying to help.. dah..

Comment: The RuntimeException is thrown with a special message so I know it is the offending line. I changed the message and the change shows up in the Expressions view in Eclipse. I have put a breakpoint on that line but it is ignored.

Comment: dude it is ignored because before eclipse hit the breakpoint error was already thrown.

Comment: Sorry you are wrong. When I call toString() the breakpoints works just fine. When it is called by the Eclipse debugger the breakpoints are ignored.

Comment: I did put the breakpoint first in `toString()` but it did not help, when it is called by the Debugger. If I call `toString()` breakpoints work just fine.

Comment: i think have some reviewing to do by ur self. you said breakpoints works just fine but then it is not fine and is ignored by debug eclipse.

Comment: can you post here the code so we can see what is the problem?> seems so hard to imagine what happens here

Comment: It is clear to me that you do not understand the question. Please read it agian.

Comment: The Eclipse debugger makes the standard call to `toString()` to display object information (if no detail formatters are provided). When that happens my breakpoints in `toString()` are ignored. When I call `toString()` the breakpoints are not ignored.